# HubTile Notification Font Size

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone, silverlight-toolkit

Do you know how can I change the font size, or maybe make the Notification text block to resize to fit the text content?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the default HubTile Control Template, the Notification text is configured like this:

```
...
<TextBlock x:Name="NotificationBlock" Grid.Row="0"
    Margin="8,8,0,6"
    Text="{TemplateBinding Notification}"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"
    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
    TextWrapping="NoWrap"
    LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"
    LineHeight="32"/>
...
```

If you want to change the font size, you will need to make a copy of the Control Template and change the relevant properties.

The easiest way to achieve that is to edit the Control Template using Expression Blend.